# border radius .less doesn't work

Tags: html, css, less

I have a site and I want to use .less instead of .css but I have a problem with border radius, if I copy the same code into a css file work in .less doens.'t work, It doesn't take my radius and the div is rectangular. I have used a compiler and It gives me 0 error. I don't know if is a problem of compatibility. this is my code that doesn't work in less but in

**css work**:

```
.colLeft{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    height:100%;
    width:24%;  
    z-index:0;
}


.colCenter{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:18%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 68%;
    background: #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px / 250px 0px 0px 250px;
    z-index:100;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

.colRight{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:81%;
    background:#fff;
    height:100%;
    width:18%;  
    z-index:1000;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px / 250px 0px 0px 250px;
}
```

**Html**:

```
<div class="colLeft" id="one">
</div>
<div class="colCenter" id="two">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="img_background">
                <img src="img/sfondi/<?php echo (basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'.php'));  ?>.jpg" alt="" class="old_img"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colRight" id="three">
        <a href="index.php" id="next">index</a>
        <a href="next.php" id="next">NEXT</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: less code is the same! I don't use different mix or function, that is the less code the same that the css

Comment: `border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px / 250px 0px 0px 250px;` so you try to `50px 0px 0px 50px / 250px 0px 0px 250px` = `0,2px 0px 0px 0,2px`?

Comment: if i write 0,2px 0px 0px 0,2px doesn't work in css and in less. if i write border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px / 250px 0px 0px 250px; work in css and don't in less

Comment: Post CSS thats compiled from LESS please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px / 250px 0px 0px 250px;
```

should be

```
border-radius: 50px 0px 0px ~"50px / 250px" 0px 0px 250px;
```

otherwise you get a division.

Less is in the process of introducing a policy of only doing division inside brackets so that valid css is unaltered, but this will be in a future release (e.g. maybe 1.4.0)

Comment: Wrap the entire thing in `~"..."`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this solution with `/` in LESS. Had me stumped for ages this and your answer made sure the `border-radius` styling was processed correctly.